# Given Key in HashTable how do I return the value if my value have multiple data types

Tags: java, hashtable

If for example, I have a hashtable with <Key, Value> where Value is a class with both:

String Name;
int Number;

Given a specific Key, how do I return a Value's Name or Number only?

Currently, I can find the Key in the hashtable and return its Value but what it returns is "Value@2c6a3f77"
I'm guessing that the @... is an index associated with how the program stores the data.

Comment: Please add more information to this post, such as the language you're writing in and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

- `map.get(key)` returns the value.
- the `getName()` and `getNumber()` are getters in the class to return their respective values.

```
YourClass instance = map.get(key);
String name = instance.getName();
String number = instance.getNumber();
```

or you can access the instance directly without an intermediate assignment.

```
map.get(key).getName() or map.get(key).getNumber();
```

The `Value@2c6a3f77` is the default return of `toString()` when you don't override it.  You can change that by doing something like this in your class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return name + ", " + number;
}
```